# Restricting parameters of for-if loops dynamically in vba

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

So I have a list of data that is set up like this

```
A B C
A B D
F X E
```

Where the first column is the ID number, the second is a date, and the third is a value.
I am taking this list of data and it gets summarized by the first value but is split based on the date in the second column

So it looks somewhat like this

```
    B     X
A  (C+D)
F         E
```

So data in a certain range of dates shows up as 2 lines in the dataset but in the output it is totaled. What I have works but with a large amount of data takes a very long time.

```
For x = 5 To lastrow
ws2.Select
z = Cells(x, 2).Value
ws1.Select
For y = 1 To 100
o = 0
m = 0
n = 0
ws1.Select
If Cells(y, 1).Value = z Then
m = Cells(y, 8).Value
n = Cells(y, 4).Value
End If
ws2.Select
If n > date1 Then
o = Cells(x, 6).Value
Cells(x, 6).Value = m + o
End If
If date1 >= n And n > date2 Then
o = Cells(x, 7).Value
Cells(x, 7).Value = m + o
End If
If date2 >= n And n > date3 Then
o = Cells(x, 8).Value
Cells(x, 8).Value = m + o
End If
If date3 >= n And n > date4 Then
o = Cells(x, 9).Value
Cells(x, 9).Value = m + o
End If
If date4 >= n And n > date5 Then
o = Cells(x, 10).Value
Cells(x, 10).Value = m + o
End If
If n <= date5 Then
o = Cells(x, 11).Value
Cells(x, 11).Value = m + o
End If
Next y
Next x
```

This is the core of what I have but is there a way to restrict the y loop to start at another number dynamically? the x=5 value is going to be the first so many entries in the y list. the x=6 value will be the next so many and so forth. is there someway to ignore rows that have already been pulled into the output?

Comment: I may have found a way to start the y loop dynamically, by adding a variable in the first if statement to change the start of the y loop `for y=p to endrow` and then in the if statemtn have it `p=p+1` when it finds a match.

Comment: This took it from taking 20 minutes on my data to about 5. Can anyone help with stopping dynamically? so when it doesn't find a match for the first time it ends the loop?

Comment: insert a boolean variable to set to true when it finds the first match, then right before Next statement test for that variable result and Exit Loop if False

Comment: I think the command is `Exit for`...Also have you considered utilizing a 2 dimensional array to iterate through your data?  It's much faster than iterating through each cell.

Comment: Did you think about using a pivot table? Its not vba, but an easy and efficient way to get your desired results (use idx as row header, date as column header and sumof value as result)